# Rotate and Resize image

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I use JSF 2 , primefaces 5.3 and i try to use rotate and resize images like Jpg, png or any other image format. But this error occurs. 
 Unable to attach behavior to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent jsf - file preview

here is my code.

```
                    <pe:imageAreaSelect id="areaSelect"  
                                        for="myImage"  
                                        widgetVar="areaSelectWidget"  
                                        autoHide="true"  
                                        handles="false"  
                                        movable="false"  
                                        persistent="false"  
                                        resizable="false"  
                                        parentSelector="#imageWrapper">  
                        <p:ajax event="selectEnd" listener="#{fileViewer.selectEndListener}" update="growl"/>  
                    </pe:imageAreaSelect>  

                    <pe:imageRotateAndResize id="rotateAndResize" for="myImage" widgetVar="rotateAndResizeWidget">  
                        <p:ajax event="rotate" listener="#{fileViewer.rotateListener}"  
                                update="growl" oncomplete="PF('areaSelectWidget').reload();"/>  
                        <pe:javascript event="resize" execute="PF('areaSelectWidget').reload();"/>  
                    </pe:imageRotateAndResize> 

                    <p:commandButton type="button" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w"
                                     value="Rotate" onclick="PF('rotateAndResizeWidget').rotateLeft(90);
                                             return false;"/>
                    <p:commandButton type="button" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e" 
                                     value="Rotate" onclick="PF('rotateAndResizeWidget').rotateRight(90);
                                             return false;"/> 
                    <p:commandButton type="button" icon="ui-icon-zoomin" 
                                     value="+"  onclick="PF('rotateAndResizeWidget').scale(1.05);
                                             return false;"/>
                    <p:commandButton type="button" icon="ui-icon-zoomout"
                                     value="-" onclick="PF('rotateAndResizeWidget').scale(0.95);
                                             return false;"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
```

public void rotateListener(final RotateEvent e) {
        final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Image rotated",  + e.getDegree() + " Degree:");

```
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void resizeListener(final ResizeEvent e) {  
    final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Image resized", "Width:" + e.getWidth() + ", Height: " + e.getHeight());  

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}  

public void selectEndListener(final ImageAreaSelectEvent e) {
    final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Area selected",
            "X1: " + e.getX1()
            + ", X2: " + e.getX2()
            + ", Y1: " + e.getY1()
            + ", Y2: " + e.getY2()
            + ", Image width: " + e.getImgWidth()
            + ", Image height: " + e.getImgHeight());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you didn't include PrimeFaces Extensions? AFAIR you need 4.0.0 which should be compatible with PF 5.3.

Otherwise i don't the exception comes from this snippet.